# The joint probability distribution of $(X,Y)$ can be completely described with the joint cdf rather than with the joint pmf or joint pdf.

Tags: probability

“The joint probability distribution of $(X,Y)$ can be completely described with the joint cdf rather than with the joint pmf or joint pdf.” This shows in the end of section 4.1 of George Casella’s classic textbook “Statistical Inference”. So why is this true? I thought cdf, pdf and mgf they all can describe the distribution.

Many thanks!

Comment: It does not say that joint pdf/pmf cannot specify the joint distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the point is that while not *all* distributions can be described by a PDF or a PMF, any distribution can be described by a CDF. For instance, PDFs can only describe absolutely continuous distributions and PMFs can only describe discrete distributions. However, any distribution has a CDF.

A characteristic function also can describe anything, while MGFs don't always exist.